# Vb.net Regex - remove html tags from string

Tags: regex, vb.net, winforms

My String Is :

```
<span class="name">name1</span><br> <span class="name">name2</span>
```

i want to remove : `"<span ...>"`  and  `"</span>"` from my string,

i can use the simple replace function, but regex is better because the operators.

i tried:

```
Regex.Replace(elm.InnerHtml, "<(.|\n)+?>", String.Empty)
```

but:

```
<(.|\n)+?>
```

remove all html tags , and i need to remove span only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace this regex `<span.+?</span>` with empty string

```
Regex.Replace(elm.InnerHtml, @"<span.+?</span>", String.Empty)
```

if you want save text between tags use this one `</?span.*?>`

```
Regex.Replace(elm.InnerHtml, @"</?span.*?>", String.Empty)
```

Comment: i tried, this regex remove the string between : <span ..>-string-</span> i want to remov the tag but keep the string between the tag.

Comment: thank you!, this regex removing "<span> and </span>" and save the string between, but the regex not removing the "class=classname"